# How to copy specific files from directories, while the directories name was extracted from an excel file using Bash script

Tags: bash, csv

I'm new in Bash and I have a list of names of directories stored in an excel file. I'd like to find those directories (they are located in different location at the computer) and to copy from each directory specific files (list of 4 files that ends with specific endings) to a remote computer.

For examples:

For a name of directory at the excel sheet - "NA123", I'd like to find it and copy it's partial content to a remote computer, for example copy the files: samples-sheet.csv, toInfo.xml, newfiles.gz, todo.csv to the remote computer, under a folder name "NA123".

How do I begin to do that?

****Editing to give an example of how it needs to be*****

A short example of the csv is as below:

```
         A
1  14RD00129_TS1_01
2  SD-2015-06_01
3  US-005
4  RA99
```

All the names at the csv are directories that can be found under `/home/bella/samples` under 3 different folders: some will be at `/home/bella/samples/gruop_1`, some at:`/home/bella/samples/gruop_2`, and some at:`/home/bella/samples/gruop_3`

So first I need to iterate through the csv file, to locate the match directory at my computer, then I need to copy 4 specific files to a remote computer with the same name of directory. Hope this is clearer...

Comment: Save your Excel file as CSV.

Comment: OK, and how should I proceed?

Comment: Iterate over the entries and use `scp` to copy the files. Or post an excerpt of your CSV for more specific hints.

Comment: Please provide sample CSV file with 2 lines, and sample destination paths (containing any spaces or special chars?)

Comment: At the csv file, there is no similarity of characteristics between the names. It is simply one column with names such as: US-005, 15RD00089_TS2, RA299. Maybe it will be easier to do with Python?

Comment: @Bella That's not the point, it is very well possible with Bash. If you provide an example input and file structure, we might suggest you a concrete approach.

Comment: OK, thanks! I added an example, hope it will help solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you CSV file should only consist of directory names then, since there's only one column. I assume there is no header line in the CSV (`A` in your example) and no line number. You can take this as a starting point:

```sh
samples='/home/bella/samples'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    dir=$(find "$samples"/gruop_{1..3} -type d -name "$line")
    scp "$dir"/{samples-sheet.csv,toInfo.xml,newfiles.gz,todo.csv} \
        user@host.com:"/path/to/$line"
done < 'file.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could do something like:

```
# create the directory on the remote:
ssh remote-ip 'mkdir -p NA123'
# copy the files to the remote in the directory just created
for f in samples-sheet.csv toInfo.xml newfiles.gz todo.csv; do scp $f remote-ip:NA123/; done
```